# Rust implement the function as long as `Integer::from` works

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm trying to implement a `num_to_rug` function, whch converts a generic number into a `rug::Integer`.

(the purpose is to call Rug's primality test, `Integer::from(n).is_probably_prime`)

This is easy to do for `u32` and `u64`, as `Integer::from` is implemented for them:

```rust
impl PrimeQ<u32> {
  fn num_to_rug(n: u32) -> Integer {
    Integer::from(n)
  }
}

impl PrimeQ<u64> {
  fn num_to_rug(n: u64) -> Integer {
    Integer::from(n)
  }
}
```

Now I want to implement this function for any type that:

- Satisfy my own `PrimeSieveTrait`
- Has `Integer::from` implemented

```rust
pub trait PrimeSieveTrait:
  AddAssign + SubAssign + MulAssign + DivAssign + integer::Roots + PrimInt + FromPrimitive {}
impl<T> PrimeSieveTrait for T
  where T:
    AddAssign + SubAssign + MulAssign + DivAssign + integer::Roots + PrimInt + FromPrimitive {}
```

How do I modify the code below so it compiles?

```rust
impl<T: ?> PrimeQ<T> {
  fn num_to_rug(n: T) -> Integer {
    Integer::from(n)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally want to use the `From<T>` trait, then this cannot be expressed as an inline trait bound – you need to use a `where` clause instead:

```
impl<T> PrimeQ<T>
where
    T: PrimeSieveTrait,
    Integer: From<T>,
{
    fn num_to_rug(n: T) -> Integer {
        Integer::from(n)
    }
}
```

A better alternative would be to use the `Into<Integer>` trait instead, in which case you only need trait bounds on `T`:

```
impl<T: PrimeSieveTrait + Into<Integer>> PrimeQ<T> {
    fn num_to_rug(n: T) -> Integer {
        n.into()
    }
}
```

(I would usually write this with a `where` clause as well, as I find that more readable.)

More generally, the trait bound `U: From<T>` implies `T: Into<U>` because of a [blanket implementation in the standard library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#impl-Into%3CU%3E). This means that using the trait bound `T: Into<U>` as in the second code snippet above makes your function more general, and it's also more convenient to use, so it should be preferred over the `From` trait bound.

Comment: Though wouldn't using `Into<Integer>` instead allow for an inline bound?

Comment: Updated the answer, and the code is now even _tested_. :)

Comment: As said in docs, you should prefer Into trait when define consumers.
`Prefer using Into over From when specifying trait bounds on a generic function to ensure that types that only implement Into can be used as well.`
Please, mention this in your answer.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html